Azure pipeline - Dynamically rendered expression inside if expression
We have a frontend monorepo build pipeline and trying to implement a dependency between build jobs.
First thing we define is the libraries to be looped over:
parameters:
  - name: librariesToBePublished
    default:
      - my-awesome-package-1
      - my-awesome-package-2
      - my-awesome-package-3
    type: object

Then we have the dependencies among these libraries:
  - name: dependencies_my_awesome_package_2
    displayName: "Library dependencies of my-awesome-package-2"
    default:
      - my-awesome-package-1
    type: object

  - name: dependencies_my_awesome_package_3
    displayName: "Library dependencies of my-awesome-package-3"
    default:
      - my-awesome-package-1
      - my-awesome-package-2
    type: object

So, the my-awesome-package-2 should not be built and deployed before my-awesome-package-1 since it is depending on it. The job to build and publish that should wait until its dependency is built and published.
This is the job definition:
- stage: Publish
    displayName: "Publish Libraries"
    jobs:
      - ${{ each package in parameters.librariesToBePublished }}:
          - job: Build_${{replace(package, '-', '_')}}
            displayName: "Build ${{package}}"
            ${{ if parameters['${{ format('dependencies_{0}', replace(package, '-', '_')) }}'] }}:
              dependsOn:
                - ${{ each dep in parameters['${{ format('dependencies_{0}', replace(package, '-', '_')) }}'] }}:
                  - Build_${{replace(dep, '-', '_')}}
            condition: succeeded()

When we try to echo the expression $[parameters['${{format('libDependencies_{0}', replace(package, '-', '_') ) }}'] it works but not in if and each parts.
What we are missing here?

Instead of using a string array:
parameters:
  - name: libraries
    type: object
    default:
      - lib1
      - lib2
      - lib3

Consider using a complex object, where you specify the dependencies for each library:
parameters:
  - name: libraries
    type: object
    default:
      - name: lib1
        displayName: 'Library 1'
        dependsOn: []
      - name: lib2
        displayName: 'Library 2'
        dependsOn:
          - lib1
      - name: lib3
        displayName: 'Library 3'
        dependsOn:
          - lib1
          - lib2

Full working example:
parameters:
  - name: libraries
    type: object
    default:
      - name: lib1
        displayName: 'Library 1'
        dependsOn: []
      - name: lib2
        displayName: 'Library 2'
        dependsOn:
          - lib1
      - name: lib3
        displayName: 'Library 3'
        dependsOn:
          - lib1
          - lib2

trigger: none

pool: Default

jobs:
  - ${{ each library in parameters.libraries }}:
    - job: ${{ library.name }}
      displayName: ${{ library.displayName }}
      dependsOn: ${{ library.dependsOn }}
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - script: echo ${{ library.name }}

Advantages:

Code is cleaner
It's possible to set multiple dependencies for each library, if needed
It's easier to add extra configuration for each library - e.g. add a condition property to specify conditions under which the job runs


I didn’t know we could have multi-level objects in Azure pipelines  Indeed, this could make our setup much simpler! I will try and get back to you Rui

@yenerunver see Parameter data types.

hey @rui, I have another related question, can you look at that one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79254376/azure-pipelines-filter-each-loop-results-with-an-if
