Azure pipelines filter "each" loop results with an "if"
We have a setup where we deploy libraries if they selected on pipeline run, like below:
parameters:
  - name: librariesToBePublished
    default:
      - name: my-awesome-package-1
        dependsOn: []
      - name: my-awesome-package-2
        dependsOn:
          - my-awesome-package-1
      - name: my-awesome-package-3
        dependsOn:
          - my-awesome-package-1
          - my-awesome-package-2
    type: object

  - name: my-awesome-package-1
    default: false
    type: boolean

  - name: my-awesome-package-2
    default: false
    type: boolean

  - name: my-awesome-package-3
    default: false
    type: boolean

Then we have a job with dependency setup with an each loop, like below:
    jobs:
      - ${{ each package in parameters. librariesToBePublished }}:
        - job: Publish_package_${{ replace(package.name, '-', '_') }}
          displayName: "Publish ${{ package.name }}"
          dependsOn:
            - ${{ each dep in package.dependsOn }}:
              - Publish_package_${{ replace(dep, '-', '_') }}
          condition: |
            and(
              succeeded(),
              eq('${{parameters[package.name]}}', true)
            )

If you check all three boxes, everything works as expected:

The problem is, if you would like to only deploy my-awesome-package-2 and not select its dependency my-awesome-package-1, it is not running since it has a dependsOn with Publish_package_my_awesome_package_1 combined with succeeded(). The first package is not selected so the dependency is skipped, not succeeding:

I would like to add something like this, if possible but no luck so far:
Option 1: Conditionally add dependencies
jobs:
      - ${{ each package in parameters. librariesToBePublished }}:
        - job: Publish_package_${{ replace(package.name, '-', '_') }}
          displayName: "Publish ${{ package.name }}"
          dependsOn:
            - ${{ each dep in package.dependsOn }}:
              - ${{ if eq('${{parameters[dep]}}', true) }}:
                - Publish_package_${{ replace(dep, '-', '_') }}
          condition: |
            and(
              succeeded(),
              eq('${{parameters[package.name]}}', true)
            )

Option 2: extend succeeded
jobs:
      - ${{ each package in parameters. librariesToBePublished }}:
        - job: Publish_package_${{ replace(package.name, '-', '_') }}
          displayName: "Publish ${{ package.name }}"
          dependsOn:
            - ${{ each dep in package.dependsOn }}:
              - Publish_package_${{ replace(dep, '-', '_') }}
          condition: |
            and(
              or(succeeded(), skipped()),
              eq('${{parameters[package.name]}}', true)
            )

Since there is no skipped() check, our only option to put or(succeeded(), eq('${{parameters[dep]}}', false)) there but the condition: part is out of the each loop.

You can simplify your code and get rid of the boolean parameters by using stages instead of jobs.
Example:
parameters:
  - name: libraries
    displayName: 'Libraries to be published'
    type: object
    default:
      - name: my-awesome-package-1
        stageName: p1
        exitCode: 1  # 0=success, other values=failure
        dependsOn: []
      - name: my-awesome-package-2
        stageName: p2
        exitCode: 1  # 0=success, other values=failure
        dependsOn:
          - p1
      - name: my-awesome-package-3
        stageName: p3
        exitCode: 0  # 0=success, other values=failure
        dependsOn:
          - p1
          - p2

stages:
  - ${{ each package in parameters.libraries }}:
    - stage: ${{ package.stageName }}
      displayName: 'Publish ${{ package.name }}'
      dependsOn: ${{ package.dependsOn }}
      jobs:
        - job: publish
          displayName: 'Publish ${{ package.name }}'
          steps:
            - checkout: none
            - script: |
                echo "Publishing ${{ package.name }}..."
                exit ${{ package.exitCode }}
              displayName: 'Publish'

Queuing a new build:

Choosing the stages:

Finally, when running the pipeline Azure DevOps will take care of the dependencies between stages for you:


this is a good suggestion but it does not solve the problem I mentioned, right? but the answer I posted solves it so probably we should mix both approaches

@yenerunver unless I misunderstood what you need, it does exactly what you're asking for. For example, if you want to deploy a package with dependencies such as package 2 or package 3 without deploying package 1 Azure DevOps will take care of the dependencies for you. Why don't you copy my sample code into a new pipeline and play with it?

the part that I think won't match what we need is, if I want to deploy only p2, it will still put p1 stage as dependency and since it will be skipped or not existing if you did not select that stage, succeeded() condition will fail. We cannot leave succeeded() out of the equation because then when p1 stage is selected and it fails, p2 stage will continue still. Right? Also, we did not use stages but we used jobs in order to have some jobs run in parallel because in stages, you wait for the whole stage to be finished before starting the next one.

maybe I was not clear on the problem in my question. Let me rephrase, the problem we have is that we can put dependencies between packages as in my example, but it causes issues when you don't want to deploy a dependent package. Then its stage/job is skipped since it is not selected, the depending job is also skipped due to succeeded() condition.

@yenerunver stages run sequentially by default but you can configure them to run in parallel by setting dependsOn: [].
Regarding We cannot leave succeeded() out of the equation because then when p1 stage is selected and it fails, p2 stage will continue still. Right? - no, that's not what happens. I'm not setting conditions manually, so if p1 fails p2 won't run.

@yenerunver I've changed my sample pipeline slightly and added a property name exitCode to simulate tasks failure/success. You can copy/paste the pipeline to run some tests. Setting exitCode to a value different than 0 will cause the correspondent stage to fail.
Go ahead and use jobs if you want to. But I repeat: using stages will simplify your code A LOT, specially because Azure DevOps will handle the dependencies for you.

According to this reference, the correct usage for these cases is and(not(failed()), not(cancelled())):

So, the solution then:
jobs:
      - ${{ each package in parameters. librariesToBePublished }}:
        - job: Publish_package_${{ replace(package.name, '-', '_') }}
          displayName: "Publish ${{ package.name }}"
          dependsOn:
            - ${{ each dep in package.dependsOn }}:
              - Publish_package_${{ replace(dep, '-', '_') }}
          condition: |
            and(
              not(failed()),
              not(cancelled()),
              eq('${{parameters[package.name]}}', true)
            )

